# Is this solution to part of Papa Rudin Chapter 2, Exercise 22 correct?

Tags: real-analysis, metric-spaces, solution-verification, semicontinuous-functions

This is part of Papa Rudin Chapter 2 Exercise 22.

Suppose that $X$ is a metric space, with metric $d$, and that $f:X \to [0, \infty]$ is lower semicontinuous, $f(p)< \infty$ for at least one $p \in X$. For $n=1,2,3,..., x \in X$, define

$$g_n (x)= \inf \{  f(p)+nd(x,p): p \in X  \}$$

and prove that $|g_n (x) - g_n (y)| \leq nd(x,y)$.

I refer to one solution from online. But I don't think it's correct.

[image]

Comment: A similar idea works, but yes, the given solution isn't correct.  You need to pick $p$ so that $f(p) + nd(x,p)$ is close to $g_n(x)$ (use an $\varepsilon >0$ to define "close")

Comment: Can you show the correct proof to me?

Comment: @Mariana Why don't you try it yourself?

Comment: @QuantumSpace Thanks, I tried by myself and I did it!

Comment: @Mariana Congratulations!